# "She's preparing up my break."

Tags: grammar

"Where's your mummy?" I asked.

> "She's preparing up my breakfast."

he said.

In dictionary, up is preposition that towards a higher value.

According to the context above, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utterance mixes two expressions-

> "She's cooking up my breakfast."

and what sounds rather formal to my Australian ears-

> "She's preparing my breakfast."

The idiomatic use of up implies coming to a conclusion (the dictionary higher value). As in-
He came up with an idea. Meaning, he thought about things and formed and idea.

I believe the usage **"preparing up"** is a literary device to suggest a very young child is speaking.

Answer (score 1):

The more usual expresions would be:

> She's preparing my breakfast.
>
> She's preparing breakfast.
>
> She's getting my breakfast ready.
>
> She's getting breakfast ready.
>
> She's making breakfast.

"Up" is incorrect here.
"Preparing" is a relatively formal word.  In my experience, a young child would be more likely to say "making breakfast" or "getting breakfast ready".

Answer (score 0):

I'm a native speaker and I have no idea what it means.  It could be a dialectal thing; perhaps "prepare up" is an idiom in what appears to be a British dialect from the use of "mummy" above.  It's not American; that's for sure.  I really don't know what the speaker is trying to say here.  I couldn't find the phrasal verb "prepare up"; however, if it should be dialectal, it may not be in the dictionary as an idiom since it may be said by just a small group in some remote area.  If you find out what it means, please let me know.  All I know is that if someone said, "She's preparing up my break," to me, I'd ask him to rephrase it because I would tell him that I didn't comprehend his original statement.

Comment: How about "She's making up my breakfast right now."

Comment: Sorry, I missed a word. It's not "break" but "breakfast."

Comment: Yes, I think the speaker is saying that she's making breakfast. The "up" is not necessary there; however, it's being used in a phrasal verb sense such as in "make up" as you say. Despite that, it's better English just to say "She's preparing breakfast" or "She's making breakfast" than to put the "up" in there. "To make up" is a phrasal verb with several meaning, one of which is "to put together", so it can be used in this instance; however, it's unnecessary. There are times it would be necessary, but not in this situation.